# What pre-industrial battle used a tactic to split the enemy force in the middle in this way?

Tags: military, identification, battle, cavalry

I remember watching a video on a pre-industrial battle (maybe even pre musket, but not sure) on a unique battle technique.  Cavalry was involved, as well as slingshot and infantry. For some reason my mind is associating it with Napoleon, but I could be wrong.  I drew a few pictures to give you an idea.

The basic formation was like such:
[image]

The RED army had cavalry and foot solders.  The goal is to split the WHITE army in two to more easily defeat it, so the RED army pulls half the WHITE army to the left simply by moving leftward:

[image]

During the entire time the RED army is moving his cavalry, behind the cavalry units are solders on foot using slingshots to attack/annoy the WHITE army.  As you can see, the WHITE army is tricked, and I think that the WHITE has little cavalry that follows RED, which means the bulk of WHITE are on foot and slower.  The next step is the genius part:

[image]

The RED army uses the speed of it's cavalry to backtrack and destroy the stationary units of the WHITE army.  Meanwhile, the RED army's foot soldiers that were behind the cavalry keep the leftward WHITE units busy (and I think because the WHITE are on foot they can't keep pace with the RED if they wanted to).

I remember that this is was considered on of the greatest battles moves according to the narrator.

Do you have any idea what battle this is?

Comment: Gaugamela aka Arbela ? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Gaugamela for diagrams a tiny bit like yours.)

Comment: Sounds a bit like Zama as well, when Scipio Africanus defeated Hannibal outside Carthage.

Comment: @kimchilover I just watched a video of the battle, but I don't think that's it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY3z3yh7a24

Comment: I just did too, and at 24 seconds in, it says "Gaugamela".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I just watch a video of the battle, and Zama isn't it, either.

Comment: I just looked at that video again, and noticed that its title is "Alexander the Great: Battle of Gaugamela 331 BC".

Comment: @kimchilover: JohnManko means that Gaugamela isn't the one he's looking for.

Comment: @gktscrk You might well be right.  But you might be wrong.  Did JohnManko say the video he provided IS the battle in question, or did he say it is NOT the battle?

Comment: I said that neither suggestion look like the battle I'm talking about, at least from how they were discussed in the videos I watched.

Comment: Uh, slingshots are a modern invention, depending on the existence of vulcanized rubber. Did the person writing the question mean to write *slingers* instead?

Comment: @llywrch oh, yeah, it could have been slingers.  Good point.